# Taylor Series Representation of $\ln(x+1) - \ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Hello I am trying to find the
Taylor   Series Representation of

> $\ln(x+1) - \ln(x)$

So I know

$$\ln(1+x)
 =\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n+1}\\$$

But for $\ln(x)$
I 'm told nothing about where it's centered and I don't believe theres a common taylor series representation for ln(x)

My teacher and TA are out of town. Is there a way I can do this without knowing where ln(x) is centered at?

Comment: Hint: $\ln(a)-\ln(b) = \ln(a/b)$.

Comment: The Taylor series centered where? You can write a Taylor series for $\ln x$ centered at every point of its domain.

Comment: @egreg thats the problem it's not specified, the TA did email me back and he said "You should be able to just center them at 0" but thats not possible..

Comment: @Temirzhan The TA's response clearly indicates a misunderstanding on the TA's part, or a misstatement of the problem.  $\log x$ has an essential singularity at $x = 0$.  It is not possible to provide a Taylor series expansion at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as *the* Taylor series representation.

The function you have is (real) analytic on its domain, which is $(0,\infty)$, which means it can be represented as a Taylor series at each point of the domain.

Choose $x=1/2$ as the center; it's simpler if you set $x=t+1/2$, so you get
$$
\ln(x+1)-\ln x=
g(t)=\ln\left(t+\frac{3}{2}\right)-\ln\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)=
\ln\frac{3}{2}-\ln\frac{1}{2}+\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{3}t\right)-\ln(1+2t)
$$
Now we can expand both parts:
$$
g(t)=
\ln3+\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2^n}{n3^n}t^n-\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2^n}{n}t^n
=\ln3+\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2^n}{n}(1+3^{-n})t^n
$$
and finally
$$
\ln(x+1)-\ln x=\ln3+\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2^n}{n}(1+3^{-n})\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\!n}
$$
Note that the radius of convergence is $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)
&=\ln(1+1/x)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{nx^n}\\
\end{array}
$

Converges for
$|1/x| < 1$
or
$|x| > 1$.

Comment: Is this a power series?

Comment: It is in $1/x$.

Answer (score 0):

The series you have for $\ln(x+1)$ works for $|x|<1$, so the series 
$$\ln(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^{n}\frac{(x-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
works for $x\in(0,2)$. Thus the series 
$$\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\left[x^{n+1}-(x-1)^{n+1}\right]$$
works for $x\in(0,1)$.